# Asterisk - get call duration of B-leg

Tags: asterisk, pbx

What is the best way to get the call duration of B-leg in Asterisk?

A num--------(a-leg)------->Asterisk PBX--------(b-leg)-----------> B num

The simple dialplan is:

```
[bleg_duration]
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
 same => n,Wait(10)
 same => n,Dial(dahdi/G1/${B_NUM},30,gS(60))
 same => n,Noop(${CDR(billsec)})
 same => n,Noop(${DIALEDTIME}) ;Time for the call (seconds)
 same => n,Noop(${ANSWEREDTIME}) ;Time from dial to answer (seconds)
 same => n,Hangup()
```

so if A number call to that dialplan, it wait for 10 seconds before connect to B number. I would like to get the duration from when the B num is answered to when B num hangup.
I think it's common need and but can't find the easy way to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can use forkCDR record.

2) You can dial via Local/ channel, second cdr record will have correct billsec.

3) You can save EPOCH(current time) and user it.

and yes, you still can use

```
${ANSWEREDTIME}: This is the amount of time for actual call.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe that if I'm using ForkCDR() then CDR will be separated to 2 parts. How I can get the duration of each part? Or i understanding wrong?

Comment: Duration will be in billsec for second one.

Comment: i known, but how can i access the second one CDR? when i call CDR(billsec) it always show the first CDR duration.

Comment: You can access second cdr from second dialplan(afer Local call). You also can mark moment when call was answered by macro of dial M(macroname).